# Ignore vendor directories in Ember rtl css

Tags: ember.js, rtlcss

We have an Ember application, where we are converting both the Vendor CSS and custom CSS into RTL CSS. We would like certain parts of vendor CSS to not be converted to RTL format. Can we exclude certain files from being converted

Comment: How do you do the RTL CSS conversion?

Comment: We are using the 'ember-cli-rtlcss' addon to do the conversion.